# How to get AngularStrap active tab?

Tags: angularjs

I am somewhat new to using Angular and AngularStrap directives.  I need to use the tab directive with static markup like the example:

```
<div data-fade="1" bs-tabs>
  <div data-title="'Home'"><p>Static tab content A</p></div>
  <div data-title="'Profile'"><p>Static tab content B</p></div>
</div>
```

On another part of the page I would like to display a div only when the first tab is selected.   The div is not part of the tabs, but is in the same overall controller.  How can I show/hide this div based on the selected tab?

Something like this?

```
<div ng-show="???? active tab stuff here ????">Home tab is selected</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3C9vTbdhLRGo3X2Nu0yw?p=preview) on the AngularStrap page the active tap is stored in

```
tabs.activeTab
```

So you can use this property to conditionally show display something else like so

```
<div ng-show="tabs.activeTab == 0">The first tab is active</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Even with non object tabs you can just bind a model against the bs-tabs to store the active ID like so:

```
<div data-fade="1" ng-model="tabs.activeTab" bs-tabs>
```

Here is an updated [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/H6e8ZSj2lyLpkvScj92y?p=preview). *(Click on the 3rd tab and see the 'Test' text appear)*

Comment: As far as I understand, this only works for object-driven tabs where the tab array is defined in the model.  I am using the markup-driven example.  I have to use this because some of the tabs are only displayed when the user is authenticated, and that is part of the ASP.Net Razor view code.  I am wondering if it is even possible to get the activeTab outside of the directive with markup-driven tabs.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the update.  I knew there must be an easier way.  Should mention that you need this code in the controller: `        $scope.tabs = [];
    $scope.tabs.activeTab = 0;`

Comment: Well the plnkr link isn't working and also this answer, details maybe, isn't working (at least at the latest versions).

If you set a scope (ex. tabs.activeTab') it will fire up on first rendering the noted in scope tab name but it will not change every time you change tab. Well i haven't find yet a solution on this, if you have one please share :)

Comment: ng-model is now deprecated, so you should use bs-active-pane instead

Answer (score 0):

I found somewhat of a hack to resolve this issue for now.  This does not seem like the best approach, so if someone has a better idea, please share.

I realized that the bsTabs directive is creating data-toggle attributes for each tab.  By watching the data-toggle shown event, I am able to recognize the tab change and display the div.  The controller code looks like this:

```
    $scope.HomeTabSelected = true;

    function watchTab() {
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
            $scope.$apply($scope.HomeTabSelected = (e.target.innerHTML == "Home"));
        })
    }

    setTimeout(watchTab, 2000);  // setTimeout necessary to allow directive to render
```

and the HTML div uses ng-show.

```
    <div ng-show="HomeTabSelected">Home tab is selected</div>
```

Comment: See me updated code. You can use the tabs.activeTab for mark-up driven tabs as well